# Mail::send() with 'mail' driver in localhost is not delivered

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm trying to send mail from my laravel application in localhost.
I followed this tutorial:

http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/sending-e-mail-with-laravel-4-using-mail/

So this is my mail.php:

```
array(

'driver'       => 'mail',

'host'      => null,

'port'      => 587,

'from'      => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),

'encryption'    => 'tls',

'username'  => null,

'password'  => null,

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'pretend' => false,

);
```

And this is in my controller:

```
Mail::send('view.view1', $data, function($message)  use ($data)
{
    $message->from($data['from'], 'Hello world!');
    $message->to($data['to'])->subject($data['object']);
});
```

I used 'mail' driver but Mail::send() is not delivered any mail and there is no error.

Is the problem is because of localhost or what?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail

Comment: In my /var/log/ there is no mail.log .
I also check by follow all the answer in this link. But cannot find the target file.

Comment: So you're sure you have `sendmail` installed?

Comment: use mailtrap.io for testing

Answer (score 0):

Install postfix or sendmail? you can also use gmail as your smtp.

Nice tut how to configure gmail as your smtp. If you dont want to do the, you need a local smtp service

Link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-emails-with-laravel-4-gmail--net-36105

Answer (score -1):

You are using mail function to send an email yeah. So, make sure that the mail server is configured correctly in the `php.ini` file. Read more about mail configuration on [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).